# Spark sql (1.4) : Get current timestamp

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know there's a 'current_timestamp' function in Spark 1.5 & above, but we're still on 1.4. How do I add a column to a DataFrame that is set to 'current timestamp'?

```
df.withColumn("date_inserted", ????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple timestamp literal should do the trick:

```
df.withColumn(
  "date_inserted",
  lit(java.sql.Timestamp.from(java.time.Instant.now)))
```

Comment: Wow! Cool. This one doesn't give Timezone but that's alright. I can now play with it. Thanks.